# Using squared difference of two images as loss function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use the SSD between two images as loss function for my network.

```py
# h_fc2 is my output layer, y_ is my label image.
ssd = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_ - h_fc2))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(ssd)
```

Problem is, that the weights then diverge and I get the error

```py
 ReluGrad input is not finite. : Tensor had Inf values
```

Why's that? I did try some other stuff like normalizing the ssd by the image size (did not work) or cropping the output values to 1 (does not crash anymore, but I still need to evaluate this):

```py
ssd_min_1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_ - tf.minimum(h_fc2, 1)))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(ssd_min_1)
```

Are my observations to be expected?

Edit:
@mdaoust suggestions proved to be correct. The main point was normalizing by batch size. This can be done independent of batch size by using this code

```py
squared_diff_image = tf.square(label_image - output_img)
# Sum over all dimensions except the first (the batch-dimension).
ssd_images = tf.reduce_sum(squared_diff_image, [1, 2, 3])
# Take mean ssd over batch.
error_images = tf.reduce_mean(ssd_images)
```

With this change, only a slight decrease of the learning rate (to 0.0001) was necessary.

Comment: Does it still diverge if you set the learning rate much lower?

Comment: I edited in the solution I'm currently using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can end up with non-finite results.

But optimizers, especially simple ones like gradient descent, can diverge if the learning rate is 'too high'.

Have you tried simply dividing your learning rate by 10/100/1000? Or normalizing by `pixels*batch_size` to get the average error per pixel?

Or one of the [more advanced optimizers](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.md#AUTOGENERATED-processing-gradients-before-applying-them.)? For example `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()` with default options.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to use it? Just swapping `GradientDescentOptimizer` with `AdamOptimizer` doesn't work.

Comment: And good idea with including batch size in the normalization, I didn't think of that!

Comment: For now, I settled for normalizing the SSD by batch_size (so it's really the SSD) and setting the learning rate much lower (divided by 1000), as you suggested. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: I always recommend normalize by the batch size. That way the error and gradients don't all change with it.