# Training a convolutional network on template images

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to design and train a convolutional neural network to identify circular cells in an image. I am training it on "cutouts" of the full images, which either have a circle in the middle of the image (positive training sample) or don't (negative training sample).

Example of an image with a circle in the middle (the heatmap colors are wonky, the images are all grayscale): https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA5gv.jpg

Rather than just classify the two types of input images (circle or not in the middle), I'd like the network output to be a binary bitmap, which is either a uniform value (e.g. -1) if there is no circle in the input image or has a "blotch" (ideally a single point) in the middle of the image to indicate the center of the circle. This would then be applied to a large image containing many such circular cells and the output should be a bitmap with blotches where the cells are.

In order to train this, I'm using the mean square error between the output image and a 2D gaussian filter (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4iA.jpg) for positive training samples and the MSE between the image and a uniform matrix with value -1 for negative training samples. Ideally, this should cause the CNN to converge on an image, which resembles the gaussian peak in the middle for positive training samples, and an image, which is uniformly -1 for negative training samples.

HOWEVER, the network keeps converging on a unversal solution of "make everything zero". This does not minimize the MSE, so I don't think it's an inherent problem with the network structure (I've tried different structures, from a single layer CNN with a filter as large as the input image to multilayer CNNs with filters of varying size, all with the same result).

The loss function I am using is as follows:

```
weighted_score = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sub(conv_squeeze, y)),
                 reduction_indices=[1, 2])
```

with `conv_squeeze` being the output image of the network and `y` being the label (i.e. the gaussian template shown above). I've already tried averaging over the batch size as suggested here:

[Using squared difference of two images as loss function in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753251/using-squared-difference-of-two-images-as-loss-function-in-tensorflow)

but without success. I cannot find any academic publications on how to train neural networks with template images as labels and as such would be grateful for anybody to point me in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Comment: In general using the MSE for training is not very easy. One other way could be to predict first if there is a cell, and then to predict its center **and** its size (predicting the gaussian seems very complicated).

Comment: Are your neurons dying? 'Make everything zero' is often a sign that neurons are dying. Did you make your initial bias for the relu neurons nonzero, and did you try different learning rates for training? It may be that you need a really small learning rate in order to have stable learning because eigenvalues and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

According to you description, I think you are facing an "imbalanced data" problem. And you can try Hinge Loss instead of MSE, it may solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Yong Li , welcome to stack overflow. Though your answer seems valid, there is a lot of possibilities and open ended solutions in your answer. You can mention  these in the comments for the question, ask for the questioner's perspective and post them as results